# Why does my simulator still show node count and FPS? [SpriteKit]

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have prepared my game to be published to the app store. Before I do that, I wanted to turn off the node count and FPS and did not want those two things to be displayed. I have a GameScene.m and a TitleScene.m. I tried `view.showsFPS = NO;` and `view.showsNodeCount = NO;` in my **GameScene.m** and it works fine. In my **TitleScene.m** I tried `self.view.showsNodeCount = NO;` and `self.view.showsFPS = NO;`, but it still shows the NodeCount and FPS. Here is my code for TitleScene.m:

```
#import "TitleScene.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation TitleScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.view.showsNodeCount = NO;
        self.view.showsFPS = NO;

        SKTexture *YellowLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"YellowLabel.png"];
        SKTexture *BlueLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"BlueLabel.png"];
        SKTexture *GreenLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"GreenLabel.png"];
        SKTexture *RedLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"RedLabel.png"];
        SKTexture *WhiteLabelTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"WhiteLabel.png"];

        SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"awsome.png"];
        background.size = CGSizeMake(640, 1136);
        background.position = CGPointMake(0,0);

        NSArray *anim = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:YellowLabelTexture, BlueLabelTexture, GreenLabelTexture, RedLabelTexture, WhiteLabelTexture, nil];

        SKSpriteNode *labelNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"WhiteLabel.png"];
        labelNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2 * 1.5);

        SKSpriteNode *startButtonNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"playButton.png"];
        startButtonNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 3);

        SKAction *actionAnimate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:anim timePerFrame:.3 resize:YES restore:NO];
        SKAction *actionRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:actionAnimate];
        [labelNode runAction:actionRepeat];

        [self addChild:background];
        [self addChild:labelNode];
        [self addChild:startButtonNode];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    GameScene* gameScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [self.view presentScene:gameScene transition:[SKTransition doorsOpenHorizontalWithDuration:1.5]];
}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: self.view is nil during a node's init

Comment: Wow! Never knew that! Thanks for the small lesson! This is why I love StackOverflow... :) @LearnCocos2D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default SpriteKit template sets  node count and fps after the initialization of the scene in `ViewController.m`, you have to remove these lines.

Comment: Thank you! I never bothered to check the ViewController and I was so interested in the Scene files.

Comment: You could also just set them to `false`, keep them there in case you wanted to see them again for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Comment showsFPS and ShowsNodeCount in your ViewController.m file;

```
//skView.showsFPS = YES;
//skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
```

Comment: was a pleasure to help